# error org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 s

Tags: selenium

public class daatadriven {

```
@Test(dataProvider="wordpressdata")

public void logintowordpress(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException

{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
    String path = System.getenv("PATH");
    System.out.println(path); // Should contain C:\Windows\system32  
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      //driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");
      driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys("");
      driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys("");
       driver.findElement(By.id("wp-submit")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      driver.quit();
      //driver.close();
      }

@DataProvider(name="wordpressdata")

public Object passData()
{
    Object[][] data= new Object[3][2];
    data[0][0]=" ";
    data[0][1]=" ";
    data[1][0]=" ";
    data[1][1]=" ";
    data[2][0]=" ";
    data[2][1]=" ";
    return data 
}
}
```

my code showing following error:

org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess
WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to find executable for: taskkill

as per google i tried to set c:\windows\system32 environment variable
but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use driver.close() in place of driver.quit() and check